# possible to set variable with multiple if statments?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can do this:

```
x ='dog'

testvar = 1 if x == 'dog'  else 0
```

My x in this case can be one of three things.  'dog', 'cat, or '' (empty)

I would like to set testvar equal to 1 if x == 'dog', equal to 2 if x== 'cat, and equal to 0 if x.isspace() == True.

What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: You can try this idiom, I think it will be more readable than an endless *if* line: http://stackoverflow.com/a/374276/520567

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can chain the `if` statements:

```
testvar = 1 if x == 'dog' else 2 if x == 'cat' else 0 if x.isspace() else None
```

You do need that last `else` statement though. Python sees this basically as:

```
testvar = 1 if x == 'dog' else (2 if x == 'cat' else (0 if x.isspace() else None))
```

with each nested conditional expression filling the `else` clause of the parent expression.

Demo:

```
>>> x = 'cat'
>>> 1 if x == 'dog' else 2 if x == 'cat' else 0 if x.isspace() else None
2
```

Another, more readable option is to use a mapping:

```
testmapping = {'dog': 1, 'cat': 2, ' ': 0}
testvar = testmapping.get(x)
```

Demo:

```
>>> testmapping = {'dog': 1, 'cat': 2, ' ': 0}
>>> testmapping[x]
2
```

Comment: ok thanks I tried the first way but didn't have the last else.